How do I structure my Hilt modules to provide an Api and Room to my repository?
I have an application that, for now, only makes some API calls when started and shows the result on screen, so my ViewModel directly commmunicates with the Api (I know that's not right). However, I plan to cache these results in a Room database. So I need to create a Repository that will handle fetching data from the API, storing them on Room and then presenting the data to the ViewModel
My Api injection is handled by Hilt, and since i'm new with dependency injection, I need some help in structuring my Hilt Modules. Currently I have one module for providing the Api and another for Room.
So my questions are, What is the best way to structure my modules so that Hilt provides both Api and Room services to my Repository, and provides the Repository to the ViewModel Do I need to put Api, Room and repo providers into one module, or do I make one for each class?
My current implementation is as follows (ommiting builder code since i dont think it matters for this question...):
Api Module:
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MKApiService {

    @Provides
    @Named("mkBaseUrl")
    fun provideBaseUrl() = "https://..."

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("mkRetrofit")
    fun provideMkRetrofit(@Named("mkBaseUrl") baseUrl: String): Retrofit {
        ...
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("mkApiService")
    fun provideApiService(@Named("mkRetrofit") retrofit: Retrofit): IMKApiService =
        retrofit.create(IMKApiService::class.java)
}

Room module:
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): AppDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            appContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "room_database"
        ).build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAgendamentosDao(database: AppDatabase): AgendamentosDao =
        database.agendamentosDao()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAgendamentosRepository(dao: AgendamentosDao): AgendamentosRepository =
        AgendamentosRepository(dao)
    // this gives an error since my repository asks for the dao and the api service
}


Don't use the  @Named("mkRetrofit") when you have only one implementation dagger or hilt already knows use when you have more than one implementation for builder class and interface...
Second thing { fun provideBaseUrl() = "https://..."} don't put URL in module instead of this put URL in object because in kotlin we have objects or companion objects for storing the constants...
your module's scope is already singleton so don't create them as an object use class for this
ROOM MODULE
don't make repository implementation in module
also don't call the dao from here use repo for calling the dao also fetching the data from the api

I actually have two api services, each with its own baseUrl, interfaces and implementations, that's why I use @Named on them.
Besides that, ys i'm planning to remove provideBaseUrl() from both since no one else uses it
Also planning to add a interface for the repo, for now I've only made the class itself. Thanks!
